# Re-Databind on RadCombobox with ajax?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been moving a lot of stuff into a webservice because it makes the whole thing make more sense to me personally. Also makes AJAX easier for me.

Right now the user will say they want to save a new contact somewhere then, through the webservice, they are added to a database and that call returns the new primary key so that I can change the RadComboBox automatically to this new record. However I can't seem to find a way  to re-bind the combo box to the database so that I can correctly set the selected value. Does anyone have any good advice on how to do this? Should I not even be using the RadCombobox? (preferably like an answer as the whole things stands but I welcome some good alternatives to the combobox)

Please keep in mind I'm avoiding postbacks at all costs (except security costs)

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the itemsrequesting even to do a partial postback to an event on the server to populate your radcombobox.  As far as causing a rebind, as far as I can tell it doesn't exists yet due to the supported webservice / itemsrequesting support. You might have to retool how you populate your combo box, but it isn't that hard.  Considering you asked this like 8 months ago I'm sure you figured it out and moved on a long time ago.  Bumped into this because I was looking for a simple client side rebind method myself, which appears not to exist.

Comment: haha well thanks for answering non-the-less. I work mostly on non-Windows tools now :)